# Odoo - How to show multi list or form in one view at same time?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-view

With Odoo10, I want to make a department-managed view. The left side of the view is a department hierarchical tree, the right side is a list of employees according to the choice of the left. So it looks like two tree view in one view. How to implement this in odoo? Is there some code examples can reference？Or if anyone can give me some advice. Thanks very much.

The view should be like this.
[image]

Comment: Ask your question in English.

Comment: @KevalMehta The image just show the view structure. The text above it has nothing to do with this question. Thanks your advice, I had erase them now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can adapt the code model from the odoo custom addon in community MUK.
[Please have a look here](https://github.com/muk-it/muk_dms)

Comment: Perfect! That is my need! Thanks very much. I need to study it for some time.